# Woocommerce change from commas to table cells

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, html-table, attributes

I want to override the way Woocommerce outputs attributes. By default, the attributes are displayed in two columns - column 1 is a label, column 2 is a comma separated list of attributes. I want to override that and have each attribute display in its own cell. Here's the original code:

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :

    if ( empty( $attribute['is_visible'] ) || ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] && ! taxonomy_exists( $attribute['name'] ) ) )
        continue;
    ?>

    <tr class="<?php if ( ( $alt = $alt * -1 ) == 1 ) echo 'alt'; ?>">
        <th><?php echo $woocommerce->get_helper( 'attribute' )->attribute_label( $attribute['name'] ); ?></th>

        <td><?php
            if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

                $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

            } else {

                // Convert pipes to commas and display values
                $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
                echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

            }
        ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>

<?php endforeach; ?>
```

I keep thinking I need to setup another `foreach` statement within the `td` but I'm not sure on how to get it setup.

Answer (score 1):

Basicly you have, with that code, this output:

```
<tr>
<th>atribute label</th>
<td>atribute name</td>
<tr>
```

So, you only need to output that something like: "atribute label - atribute name", for that you only need to remove the th tags and put the code for label inside the td ones.

Someting like this:

```
<tr class="<?php if ( ( $alt = $alt * -1 ) == 1 ) echo 'alt'; ?>">


    <td>
        <?php echo $woocommerce->get_helper( 'attribute' )->attribute_label( $attribute['name'] ); ?>
        <?php
        if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

            $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

        } else {

            // Convert pipes to commas and display values
            $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
            echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_attribute', wpautop( wptexturize( implode( ', ', $values ) ) ), $attribute, $values );

        }
    ?></td>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out...I needed to adjust the the `foreach` statement and how the cells appear in the row (and what appears in them), here's my finalized code which is working, however, I would love suggestions to improve it:

```
<?php foreach ( $attributes as $attribute ) :

    if ( empty( $attribute['is_visible'] ) || ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] && ! taxonomy_exists( $attribute['name'] ) ) )
        continue;
    ?>  
    <tr>
        <th scope="row"><?php echo $woocommerce->attribute_label( $attribute['name'] ); ?></th>
        <?php
            if ( $attribute['is_taxonomy'] ) {

                $values = woocommerce_get_product_terms( $product->id, $attribute['name'], 'names' );
                foreach ( $values as $value ) :
                    echo '<td>'; 
                    echo $value;
                    echo '</td>';
                endforeach;
            } else {

                $values = array_map( 'trim', explode( '|', $attribute['value'] ) );
                foreach ( $values as $value ) :
                    echo '<td>'; 
                    echo $value;
                    echo '</td>';
                endforeach;
            }
        ?>
    </tr><?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I followed your code, but it did not work for me. The commas are still there. Was it the product-attributes.php file you edited? IS there more than one file that needs to be edited? I'm running my WP on localhost, don't know if that makes a difference or not.

Comment: Yes, it was the product-attributes.php file. I copied the file from woocommerce plugin folder to wp-content/themes/mytheme/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php and made the change there. This way it is upgrade friendly. Running on localhost should not make a difference.

Comment: Ok I figured it out, the theme I'm using (Avada by Theme Fusion) seems to keep Woocommerce files in 2 directories, probably to be, as you said, upgrade friendly; so I had already had 2 copies of the file, first path was wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/templates/single-product/product-attributes.php, second path was wp-content/themes/Avada/woocommerce/single-product/product-attributes.php. Turns out editing the file under wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/ did nothing, had to make changes wp-content/themes/Avada/woocommerce/. Worked after that : )